# Error when creating an interrupt-able thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, interrupt

I want to create a thread that can be interrupted while waiting (it waits data from other processes and I want to stop the process in nice way).

I've read the 9.2 part of [C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition), and I've tried to implement that ideas, but I've some problem and I don't know where to check.

This is my code based on that example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

// Exception that should be raised when there's an interruption.
// It's raised when the thread is interrupted, so we can catch
// it and finish the thread execution.
class InterruptedException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  InterruptedException(const std::string& message) : std::runtime_error(message) {}
  virtual ~InterruptedException() {}
};

// Interrupt flag. This class represents a local-thread flag that
// tells if the thread is interrupted or not.
class InterruptFlag {
public:

  InterruptFlag() :
    m_threadConditionVariable(nullptr),
    m_threadConditionVariableAny(nullptr) {}

  void set() {
    m_flag.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_setClearMutex);
    if (m_threadConditionVariable) {
      m_threadConditionVariable->notify_all();
    }
    else if (m_threadConditionVariableAny) {
      m_threadConditionVariableAny->notify_all();
    }
  }

  template <typename Lockable>
  void wait(std::condition_variable_any& cv, Lockable& lk) {
    struct CustomLock {
      InterruptFlag* m_self;
      Lockable& m_lk;

      CustomLock(InterruptFlag* self, std::condition_variable_any& cond, Lockable& lk) :
        m_self(self),
        m_lk(lk) {
        m_self->m_setClearMutex.unlock();
        m_self->m_threadConditionVariableAny = &cond;
      }

      void unlock() {
        m_lk.unlock();
        m_self->m_setClearMutex.unlock();
      }

      void lock() {
        std::lock(m_self->m_setClearMutex, lk);
      }

      ~CustomLock() {
        m_self->m_threadConditionAny = nullptr;
        m_self->m_setClearMutex.unlock();
      }
    };

    CustomLock cl(this, cv, lk);
    InterruptPoint();
    cv.wait(cl);
    InterruptPoint();
  }

  void setConditionVariable(std::condition_variable& cv) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_setClearMutex);
    m_threadConditionVariable = &cv;
  }

  void clearConditionVariable() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_setClearMutex);
    m_threadConditionVariable = nullptr;
  }

  bool isSet() const {
    return m_flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }

private:

  std::atomic<bool> m_flag;
  std::condition_variable* m_threadConditionVariable;
  std::condition_variable_any* m_threadConditionVariableAny;
  std::mutex m_setClearMutex;
};

// Thread-local interrupt flag instance. The variable should be
// created for every thread, since it's thread_local.
thread_local InterruptFlag ThisThreadInterruptFlag;

// Convenience class for cleaning the flag due to RAII.
struct ClearConditionVariableOnDestruct {
  ~ClearConditionVariableOnDestruct() {
    ThisThreadInterruptFlag.clearConditionVariable();
  }
};

// Function that throws the exception that tells that the thread
// is interrupted. For doing it checks the state of ThisThreadInterruptFlag.
void InterruptionPoint() {
  if (ThisThreadInterruptFlag.isSet()) {
    throw InterruptedException("Interrupted");
  }
}

// Function that must be used inside the thread function body for waiting.
// It waits for the condition variable, when it notifies from other threads,
// but it also notifies if the thread is interrupted.
void InterruptibleWait(std::condition_variable& cv, std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lk) {
  InterruptionPoint();
  ThisThreadInterruptFlag.setConditionVariable(cv);
  ClearConditionVariableOnDestruct guard;
  InterruptionPoint();
  cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
  InterruptionPoint();
}

// This class represents the interruptible thread. It adds a interrupt()
// method that when called interupts the thread execution, if it's waiting
// at some point where InterruptibleWait function is locked.
class Interruptible {
public:

  template <typename FunctionType>
  Interruptible(FunctionType f) {
    std::promise<InterruptFlag*> p;
    m_internalThread = std::thread([f, &p]() {
      p.set_value(&ThisThreadInterruptFlag);
      try {
        f();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException) {

      }
      });
    m_flag = p.get_future().get();
  }


  void join() {
    m_internalThread.join();
  }

  void detach() {
    m_internalThread.detach();
  }

  bool joinable() const {
    return m_internalThread.joinable();
  }

  void interrupt() {
    if (m_flag) {
      m_flag->set();
    }
  }

private:

  std::thread m_internalThread;
  InterruptFlag* m_flag;
};

std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << "Interrupting thread example" << std::endl;
  bool test = false;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  auto f = [&cv, &test]() {
    test = true;
    InterruptibleWait(cv, lk);
    // Since it locks forever, it should never reach this point.
    test = false;
  };
  Interruptible interruptibleThread(f);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
  // We interrupt the function while it's blocked in InterruptibleWait
  interruptibleThread.interrupt();
  interruptibleThread.join();
  std::cout << "test value is " << std::boolalpha << test << ". It should be true." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Basically I create a `Interruptible` class representing a thread that can be interrupted. I interrupt it during its execution by calling its `interrupt()` method. The thread can be interrupted if it's locked with in a `InterruptibleWait` function call. This function behave like a `std::condition.wait()`, in fact it wants a reference to it, but it also handle the interruption flag.

If I start the program. I obtain an error from Visual Studio when running.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What should I do in order to make `InterruptibleWait` work correctly?

Comment: Re: "I obtain an error from Visual Studio when running." What is the error message?

Comment: O obtain a Debug error because abort() is called. If I click on retry I obtain an exception thrown on system `mutex` class, saying "operation not permitted: operation not permitted". The exception is thrown inside `InterruptibleWait`, in the condition `wait_for`.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess based on the given information:

The exception isn't caught in the thread entry point function, and escapes that function. When this happens in a thread started by std::thread, abort is called for you (indirectly through std::terminate) by the std::thread implementation, as required by the standard. To fix this, try catching all exceptions in the function passed to std::thread.

See the cppreference articles on std::thread and std::terminate